# Saving Angular expression output in PHP variable

Tags: php, angularjs, variables

How I can save the expression output in a php variable?

I am looking for something like this

```
$document_id = {{Document.id}};
```

Thanks

Comment: Ajax or regular form submit, the usual way of sending js vars to php

Comment: You have to issue an HTTP request to your server via Angular.

Answer (score 1):

use $http service injecting it to controller.
Use its ajax function ( here i am doing post method, but you can use get - look at documentation of

> $http

directive.

```
.controller('MyCtrl',['$http',function($http){
//your additional code
    $http.post('/myurl.php', {param:'Document.id'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // execute after succesfully sent
    })
}]);
```

Then create a php file named myurl.php
and in it:

```
$document_id = $_POST['param'];
```

The post url 'myurl.php' should reflect current php url, so it depends on application structure. You can also set direct url like: 'localhost:8080/myurl.php'. If you use on same domain it is ok, otherwise you can get origin policy problem. 
What is done here is sending through AJAX to server where php interpreter handle it.